# Spring Security returning 404 with PUT method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use a rest controller to add items to a shopping cart. When sending a PUT to localhost:8080/rest/cart/add/P1234 to update cart with new item, I keep getting 404 error.
Haven't found anything that addresses this problem. 
When using Postman, I just got a login redirect, which is what gave me the idea to consider security... after disabling all security components the code works.
Can anyone point me to what I've done wrong to get to this problem?

I am using Spring Boot, with my WebSecurityConfig.java as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .deleteCookies("my-remember-me-cookie")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
        ;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest/cart")
public class CartRestController {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ProductController.class);
    @Autowired
    private CartService cartService;
...
@PutMapping("/add/{productId}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable("productId") String productId, HttpSession session) {
        log.info(">> received add request for " + productId);
        cartService.addItem(session.getId(), productId);
    }
}
```

controllers.js

```
var cartApp = angular.module('cartApp', []);

cartApp.controller('cartCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



    $scope.addToCart = function(productId) {
        console.log("adding to Cart: " + productId);
        $http.put('/rest/cart/add/' + productId)
            .success(function(data) {
                alert("Product Successfully added to the Cart!");
            });
    };

});
```

And finally, html using thymeleaf:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-large"  th:attr="ng-click='addToCart(\'' + ${product.productId}+ '\')'">
                        <span class="glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon"></span> [[#{button.orderNow}]]
                    </a>
```

Comment: You must provide some sort of authentication token when requesting an authenticated endpoint. I don't see any in your angular code (`$http.put('/rest/cart/add/' + productId)`)

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko thanks for that. although I know almost nothing of Angular, so would have to look into how that is done. Any ideas where to look? Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: usually token is passed as custom http-header of request. IDK how to do it in Angular either